# Adding button event arguments to a method

Tags: c#, winforms, button, events

I am working on a game where a user moves around a 10x10 grid of buttons. The buttons are added to a 2d array and are displayed as shown below. Currently I have the starting position (black player tile) set to index 1 when the form loads. What I am trying to figure out is how I can introduce a button event method that I can use to navigate the tiles.

Here is what the grid looks like:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
    private readonly int _xAxis = 10;

    private readonly int _yAxis = 10;

    private int _count = 1;

    private void DrawButtonArray()
    {
        Button[] buttons = new Button[_xAxis * _yAxis];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _xAxis; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _yAxis; j++)
            {
                Button gridBtn = new Button
                {
                    Size = new Size(60, 55),
                    Location = new Point(175 + j * 60, 55 + i * 55),
                    Text = _count.ToString()
                };

                gridBtn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);

                buttons[index++] = gridBtn;
                _count++;
                Controls.Add(gridBtn);

                if (index == 1)
                {
                    gridBtn.BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What Id hope to achieve is a mouse click event (or possibly WASD key press) that moves the "player" from one button to another. The current idea I have is to set the next button that is clicked to the colour of the current position, then set the current positions colour to the default grey. I just need to know how I could add these event args to the method that doesn't contain them. How might I add them?

Answer (score 0):

I created a method that works, but it might not be the best:

```
    private void DrawButtonArray()
    {
        Button[] buttons = new Button[_xAxis * _yAxis];
        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _xAxis; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _yAxis; j++)
            {
                Button gridBtn = new Button
                {
                    Size = new Size(60, 55),
                    Location = new Point(175 + j * 60, 55 + i * 55),
                    Text = _count.ToString()
                };

                gridBtn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);

                if (currentIndex == 0)
                {
                    gridBtn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
                }

                buttons[currentIndex++] = gridBtn;

                _count++;

                Controls.Add(gridBtn);
            }
        }

        currentIndex = 1;

        foreach (Button nextIndex in buttons)
        {
            nextIndex.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (nextIndex.Text == (currentIndex + 1).ToString()
                    || nextIndex.Text == currentIndex.ToString()
                    || nextIndex.Text == (currentIndex - 1).ToString()
                    || nextIndex.Text == (currentIndex + 10).ToString()
                    || nextIndex.Text == (currentIndex - 10).ToString())
                {
                    buttons[currentIndex - 1].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);
                    currentIndex = int.Parse(nextIndex.Text);
                    nextIndex.BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move");
                }
            };
        }
    }
```